# What is the difference between "confint" and "confint.default" when calculating confidence intervals for a logit model in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I want to calculate confidence intervals for some parameters of a logit model in R. I have read the documentation of both *confint* and *confint.default* but I haven't been able to understand the information about when it is appropriate to apply each function. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to call `confint`. `confint` is a "generic" function. It "dispatches" the appropriate "method" function based on the type of model object you provide as an argument.

If you provide `confint` with a model created with the `glm` function, `confint` dispatches the function `confint.glm`. (If you run `class(x)`, where `x` is the name of your model object, you'll see its class is `glm`, and this is what tells `confint` which method to dispatch.) Calling `confint.default` will force the use of the "default" method. The help for `confint` explains that "the default method assumes normality", so it will likely give incorrect results when used on a logistic regression model.

You can see all of the types of models that `confint` has methods for by running `methods(confint)` and you'll see that one of them is `confint.glm`.

This is all related to how object oriented programming works in R. See, for example, [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) for details.